# SSRS able to handle input forms?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a quite excessively used SSRS (2008) installation, which generates tons of reports.

Now some users filed a demand that they do need a way to enter some data into SQL databases through SSRS as well. As usual they dream of doing everything in one system, browser-based, and Reporting Services is already in place

A parallel tool/service is denied by both the SQL server admins and the SSRS users:

- SQL server admins do not want an additional service (IIS) installed
- SSRS users want the solution as tightly as possible integrated into SSRS.

there aree two ways I can think of how I could (technically) achieve this:

--A: add a form to the list of reports --
Is there a way to add a plain html form to the list of reports and use it to input data into databases? I'd consider this possible if a html form is

a) delivered to the client via the SSRS web server once the user klicks a link, just like this happens with reports, and
b) if the form, once submitted, can be grabbed by some code somewhere on the SQL server, by implementing kind of "extension" to SSRS service, assuming that soch an interface/hook might exist somewhere in the depth of the SSRS object model.

--B: encapsulate SSRS into some larger scale html/asp.net based solution. Technically live with IIS on the SQL server, and add a wrapper around the SSRS adding some plain vanilla html input forms. Main concern: is it possible to maintain a consistent security context between the forms and the reports part

And thoughts/leads/pointers to docs and samples welcome

Thx, Al